# What could be best approach for regression suite for microservices, Can Scala be used for that?

Tags: scala, testing, junit, jmeter, scalatest

I was asked to prepare a regression suite for testing micro-services, for that I need to:
- Run scripts
- Run different API's (can be multiple for scenarios to be used in next API)
- Publish result in some presentable format

My own first choice was Jmeter for this, but senior resource didn't agreed and I was asked to use SCALA, while working with Scalatest , I am stuck with Futures as most of my testing revolves around calling Restful API's.

I still think Jmeter is better for what I am doing, but don't have solid base for that, can anyone suggest which one I should go for?

Comment: If you want to do performance regression with Scala, you can use Gatling http://gatling.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely YES, I'm using scalatest for [unit-testing](/questions/tagged/unit-testing), [integration-testing](/questions/tagged/integration-testing), [component-testing](/questions/tagged/component-testing) and [shakedown-testing](/questions/tagged/shakedown-testing) my microservice.

Have not used much JMeter, I tried it for perf testing my microservice, was bit frustrating to me, immediately gave up.

Scalatest has been so `f#*$_&g` productive for me.

Example for a very simple integration testing, (I'm using `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` as my API endpoint which is online API)

```
class SomeHttpFlowSpecs extends HttpFlowSpecs {

  feature("Getting user posts on my API server") {

    scenario("As a software engineer, I want to receive the user posts when I call the endpoint") {

      When("I send a GET request to the http endpoint")
      val response = doHttpGet("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")

      Then("I receive 200 response back with the user posts")
      assert(response.getStatusLine.getStatusCode == 200)

      val expectedJson =
        """
          |{
          |  "userId": 1,
          |  "id": 1,
          |  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
          |  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
          |}
        """.stripMargin

      assert(JSON.parseRaw(responseContent(response)) == JSON.parseRaw(expectedJson))
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote my own `HttpFlowSpecs` as a Util for making http calls and handling responses. The calls are synchronous to me unlike you are saying `Future` responses. I'm using very well known `apache httpclient` for http communication.

```
class HttpFlowSpecs extends extends FeatureSpec with GivenWhenThen with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  def doHttpGet(endpoint: String): CloseableHttpResponse = {
    val httpRequest = new HttpGet(endpoint)
    val response = (new DefaultHttpClient).execute(httpRequest)
    response
  }

  def doHttpPost(endpoint: String, content: String, contentType: String = "application/json"): CloseableHttpResponse = {
    val httpRequest = new HttpPost(endpoint)
    httpRequest.setHeader("Content-type", contentType)
    httpRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(content))

    val response = (new DefaultHttpClient).execute(httpRequest)
    response
  }

  def responseContent(response: CloseableHttpResponse): String = {
    val responseBody: String = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity.getContent))
      .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))

    println("Response body = " + responseBody)
    responseBody
  }
}
```

Here's a very simple [conifers-spec](https://github.com/nihil-os/conifers-specs) I use for my testing.

I use [pegdown - Java Markdown processor](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown/) with scalatest for html reporting as below,

[image: pegdown]

**Also, you can see all your scenarios in a very readable format, see one of my components tests** in my project,

[image: reports]

### How I run my tests

```
mvn clean test
```

Hope this is useful, let me know if any questions, would be happy to help.

Comment: This is really helpful but it looks like I need to re-structure what I have been writing. For http calls, I followed Play WS, and was initiating a Akka Actor system and createing WS client for http request, but those are Async calls, which made me wondering around, as for component/integration level test I need to call set of API's getting response and utilizing them is tough with Async calls.  Let me know if can get in touch with you somehow, it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: You might consider using `AsyncFeatureSpec` for async assertions which is very cool for such scenarios. That way you dont hav to Await for the response manually, [example here](https://github.com/nihil-os/conifers-specs/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/specs/flow/http/AsyncSomeHttpFlowSpecs.scala#L45). Im using akka-http as a client in this example. Conceptually it'd be similar to PlayWSclient. [email me](http://prayagupd.github.io/) or [create issue](https://github.com/nihil-os/conifers-specs/issues) whatev is comfortable. I will try to help if I could. Unless I am sucked into prod issues :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go for JMeter, main features are:

- You have everything you need out of the box (samplers, pre/post processors, assertions, [reporting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), etc)
- JMeter tests can be [scaled](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) to run on multiple machines
- JMeter tests can be created using GUI, no programming language knowledge is required

There is also [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) tool where tests are being created using Scala-based [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), however according to [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) JMeter is better in terms of protocols support, scalability and throughput.